# Enter if consecutive numbers in an array are separated by the same magnitude

Tags: javascript, java, matrix

I have to do this: perform a function or method that receives an array of n numbers and detects if all consecutive numbers are separated by the same magnitude, but I have to do it in JavaScript.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ar[]={194, 54, 23, 7, 3, 6, 8};
    if(array(ar)){
        System.out.println("Son consecutivos");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No son consecutivos");
    }
}

public static boolean array(int arr[]){
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   if((arr[i] + 1) != arr[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const areConsecutive = (array) => {
  const sorted = [...array].sort((a,b) => a-b);
  const magnitude = sorted[1] - sorted[0];
  for(let i=0; i<sorted.length - 1; i++) {
    if(sorted[i+1] - sorted[i] !== magnitude) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, Since array could be a keyword I changed it to "**aray**"

```
const ar =[194, 54, 23, 7, 3, 6, 8];
// const ar =[1, 3, 5, 7];
if (aray(ar)) {
    console.log("Son consecutivos");
} else {
    console.log("No son consecutivos");
}

function aray(arr) {
    let result = false;
    if (!arr) {
        return result;
    }
    if (arr.length <= 2) {
        return result;
    }
    arr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
    });
    let i = 0;
    let magnitude = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]);    
    for(let i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if(Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]) != magnitude) {
            
            return result;
        }
    }    
    result = true;
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
No son consecutivos
```

Comment: Hello Rakumar M.  I try to execute it and it only sends me pure non-consecutive numbers, more than anything what I try to do is, that my array detects if all the numbers in consecutive position are separated by the same magnitude .. example, 1,3,5 the separation magnitude is 2 and they are positioned consecutively. therefore it would send me true, in opposite bag it would send me false.

Comment: I assumed your code was working and I just tried porting it to JavaScript, But now I have updated the code as per your requirement.